# How to insert a paragraph object in listItem preserving the formating of each word of the paragraph?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Following the [documentation sample](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item), I'm trying to create a function that search for a numerated list in a google document and, if it finds it, adds a new item to the list. My code works well (thanks to @Serge insas for previous help) with strings, but not with paragraphs objects. I know I could get the paragraph text and add it to listItem, but then I lose the formating. Is there a way to insert a paragraph preserving all it's formating? (I know I could use `var newElement = child.getParent().insertListItem(childIndex, elementContent.getText())` do insert text without words formating)

Here the code:

```
function test() {      
  var targetDocId = "1A02VhxOWLUIdl8LTV1tt2S1yASDbOq77VbsUpxPa6vk";  
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById(targetDocId);
  var body = targetDoc.getBody();
  var elementContent = targetDoc.getChild(2); // a paragraph with its formating
  var childIndex = 0;
  for (var p= 0; p< targetDoc.getNumChildren(); p++) {
    var child = targetDoc.getChild(p);    
    if (child.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM){
      while(child.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM){
        child = targetDoc.getChild(p)
        Logger.log("child =  " + child.getText())
        childIndex = body.getChildIndex(child);
        Logger.log(childIndex)
        p++
      }
      child = targetDoc.getChild(p-2);
      var listId = child.getListId();
      if (child.getText() == '') {
         childIndex = childIndex -1;
      }
      Logger.log(childIndex)
      var newElement = child.getParent().insertListItem(childIndex, elementContent);
      newElement.setListId(child);
      var lastEmptyItem = targetDoc.getChild(childIndex +1).removeFromParent();      
      break;
    }
```

Here a screen shot of my targetDoc (note the second item, `Paragraph`):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I've come up with a solution and will leave here for anyone that may need it. It is not complete, as I have yet to find a way to copy any Inline Drawing and Equation to a new element...

Anyways, here is my code, it will work well if the paragraph you want to convert to a list item only has text and Inline Images.

```
function parToList() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  //gets the paragraph at index 1 on body -> can be changed to what you want
  var par = body.getChild(1);
  var childs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i<par.getNumChildren(); i++) {
    var child = par.getChild(0);
    childs.push(child);
    child.removeFromParent();
  };
  par.removeFromParent();
  //puts the list item on index 1 of body -> can be changed to the wanted position
  var li = body.insertListItem(1, "");
  childs.reverse();
  for (var j in childs) {
    var liChild = childs[j];
    var childType = liChild.getType();
    if (childType == DocumentApp.ElementType.EQUATION) {
      //still need to find a way to append an equation
    } else if (childType == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_DRAWING) {
      //still need to find a way to append an inlineDrawing
    } else if (childType == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE) {
      li.appendInlineImage(liChild);
    } else if (childType == DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT) {
      li.appendText(liChild);
    };
  };
};
```

Cheers